# SharePoint search using Wildcard suffix matching

Tags: sharepoint-search

Can anyone please guide me whether I can perform a wildcard suffix matching in a SharePoint 2013 Search. For eg. *card which should return search results ending with the word "card".

The KQL(Keyword Query Language) in SharePoint Search gives successful results for the wildcard prefix matching viz. card* returning results starting with the word "card". So is there any solution where I can perform wildcard suffix matching to get the desired results?

Answer (score 1):

No, SharePoint does not support suffix matching. It only supports prefix matching.